# What does 'program against' mean?

Tags: json

I'm not a programmer but I work on IT materials an a translator and translation reviewer in Korea.

I came across the following sentence at work:

Once the NuGet package has been added and the project references updated you can **program against the APIs** as you would with any project reference.
(source: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-studio/nuget_walkthrough/)

Anyone can please explain what 'program against the APIs' mean?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

It simply means to use the APIs. For example : "Once the NuGet package has been added and the project references updated you can program using the NuGet APIs as you would with any project reference."

Comment: Wow, thank you for the quick answer. I appreciate it :)